# Why 20W USB chargers are rated for 3A@5V?

Tags: power-supply, charger

Like the title says, I'm confused as to why a "20W" USB charger is only rated for 3A.
Power = V*A hence A = 20W/5V = 4A
Am I missing something big here?

Comment: Please post a photo of rating plate/engraving.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are missing that it does not use 5V to get 20W, you just assume it does. Or that you assume 20W is also available at 5V but it isn't.

Assuming this is about USB-C, the cables are specified for 3A, and without a special electronic marker chip, no more than 3A is allowed through the cable.

Answer (score 2):

USB-C can deliver much more than 15W. For example [this](https://s.click.aliexpress.com/e/_De5i1FV) Huawei fast charger:

[image]

The cable has to support the current and the device at the other end has to negotiate the voltage if it is to be more than 5.0V.

Answer (score 0):

Bigger numbers sell more!

All power supplies have maximum current and power. So if a power supply can deliver 1A at 20V (20W) but only 3A at 5V (15W), by the magic touch of the Marketing fairy, it's a 20W power supply. If it was described as "20W max" power supply, it would be truthful.

Note this is different from Amazon/Aliexpress ratings. Using this nomenclature, a power supply that can deliver 1A at 20V or 3A at 5V is a 60W power supply, because it can do 20V and 3A. Not at the same time, of course, but who cares about that.

Answer (score -1):

If it is a USB power supply then it is likely that the output voltage is fixed at 5V. So talk of variable or multi-output supplies is irrelevant.
Most likely it **consumes** 20W in order to **deliver** 15W = 5V @ 3A (that is 75% efficient)
If this is not the case, please give us more details, name, use and a couple of images, one of the overall device and one of the ratings plate.

Comment: Peter - Hi, Re: "*If it is a USB power supply then it is likely that the output voltage is fixed at 5V. So talk of variable or multi-output supplies is irrelevant.*" FYI with the advent of USB PD (Power Delivery) that is increasingly no longer true and negotiated voltages above 5 V on a USB-attached device are becoming more common. For example [this official Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT210133) shows that its 20 W USB-C adapter uses USB-PD and can negotiate up to 9 V @ 2.22 A to achieve (approx) 20 W with compatible devices (but only 15 W with non USB-PD 5 V-only devices).

Comment: And if it's a classic 5V wall wart? Without further information we can't answer this question with any certainty.

Comment: Peter - "*Without further information we can't answer this question with any certainty.*" But you *did* choose to answer it, so I'm just pointing out (with a link to a reputable source - I could have linked to the USB PD spec too, but it's a longer document) that claiming "*talk of variable or multi-output supplies is irrelevant*" no longer applies to USB power supplies - it *can be* relevant. Does it apply here? We don't know. But that doesn't alter the fact that some USB power supplies do now have variable voltage outputs, so it is no longer irrelevant. Hope that explains my concern. Thanks.